# Manipulate URL $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, uri, httprequest

This is my url:
http://localhost/framework/index.php

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Would output: /framework/index.php

But If my url was:

http://localhost/framework/

The output would be:

```
/framework/
```

And If I move the file, yeah you get the idea.

How do I grab the content after folders/eventually index.php file? My idea is to have index.php as a front controller.

If I have:

http://localhost/framework/index.php/test/test

I only want the test/test part.

http://localhost/framework/test/test

I only want the test/test part.

Comment: I have only been looking in $_SERVER variables too see If I could find any that give me what I want, without any luck. PATH_INFO had potential, but not what Im really looking for.

Comment: Use `mod_rewrite` and rewrite everything to `index.php/your/path`. Your `.htaccess` would look like: https://gist.github.com/1320584. Then you could use Daveo`s solution safely.

Comment: If I have folders, will that too be redirected? Such as css/

Comment: No. Therefor the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. So if you access any valid file or folder, mod_rewrite won't change anything. But if you go to for example `http://yourdomain.com/this/is/a/test`, then you end up (internally, the browser url bar keeps unchanged) with `http://yourdomain.com/index.php/this/is/a/test`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can automatically detect the base uri and remove it, leaving you with the test/test part.

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']))
{
    // Uri info does not contain docroot or index
    $uri = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
}
else
{
    if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
    {
       $fullUrl = 'http://'
                  . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : '')
                  . ((isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '');

       $uri = parse_url($fullUrl, PHP_URL_PATH);
    }
    else if(!empty($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))
    {
       $uri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }
}

$baseUri = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], "/")+1);
$uri = str_replace($baseUri, '', $uri);
```

**Edit:** mAu's comment above is correct. I was under the assumption you was already using mod rewrite.

Comment: What if (as given in the question as one possibility) `index.php` is not part of the request URI?

Comment: Updated code. The above works fine for me. The script name will still be valid regardless of whether it appears in the absolute url or not.

Comment: @Daveo although, the answer is good, can you please try to give more insight of the answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711371