# Custom profile URL for own site, been though various posts..!

Tags: url-rewriting, user-profile, custom-url

I've been through a few similar posts, 
[Facebook Like Custom Profile URL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595556/facebook-like-custom-profile-url-php)

[Custom URL / Apache URL Rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689446/custom-url-apache-url-rewriting)

But its still not clear, the actual method/process is not available..
Guys , little more guidance would do a lot..

**I would like to put forward the questions here:**

1. Users should have a chance to decide what is their url, Just like in case of fb, twitter
   for example: www.facebook.com/harry.inaction
2. I am using the linux, apache, mysql, php  environment for this.
3. Users are identified based on their user id's which get created automatically when they join in

And I fail at the very first step, seriously I don't know get started.

Thanks

Comment: This forum is to receive help with specific problems. It is not a general help or discussion forum. Sorry. If you have a specific question then ask it.

Comment: The problem is specific.. I want to learn how to allow users to have their own profile url's

Comment: Sorry, but what is specific about this question? It is a 'how are urls generally constructed? Is there a best practice there?' question. A specific question is something like: here is my code, I get this error, what is wrong?.

Comment: Here my question is.. How do I get started..??

Comment: Then it is probably best if you start by asking a specific question. No, don't get this wrong, I am not trying to be unfriendly. But if you do not tell what you actually want to do, how those urls should look like, what environment/language you want to use and how your users are organized/identified and and and, then there is little we can answer to.

Comment: Why can't you simply write what you want? How _are_ the "urls in fb, twitter" you cite? I _guess_ the "p" in LAMP stands for PHP? Or is it Perl? Or Python? Write how the url should look like and what step it is that you fail with.

Comment: Am I that bad at explanations, though I edited again.. thought it was obvious

Comment: My @arkascha can you please help me get started..!!

Comment: This forum is not for offering general "getting started help", really sorry. However since I know the feeling of "help, where to start?" I offer this: you can address me (nickname 'arkascha') at irc freenode typically in these channels: #linux, #kde, #owncloud. Ping me there and we can have a little chat. I think an interactive explanation is the only way for such general questions. So: get an irc client (you need it anyway for help in programming), connect to some freenode.net irc server and join one of the channels mentioned. There write: "arkascha: ping" if you see me in the list of users.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be impossible to put any details as an answer because you've got to *build* this system of yours and there's more than one way to do it. Design decisions will need to be made based on the way you want things to work and what you already have (they're going to have to work together in some way).

Say you've already got a system for creating users (and it sounds like you do) and you already have a system for viewing profiles. You'll need to extend this system so that you store an extra "my_vanity_url" field in your user table in your database. This field needs to be unique. When a user edits their profile, they have the option of changing this to whatever they want (limiting it to only letters and numbers and dashes for simplicity).

Next, when you display this profile, say it is via `/profile.php`, your code needs to check a few things.

1. First it needs to check how it's called, looking at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` you can see either `/user/some-vanity-name` or `/profile.php?u=1234`.
2. If it's the latter, you need to redirect the browser, do a database lookup to see who the user with user_id `1234` is.
3. Pull the "my_vanity_url" column out of the database for this user and redirect the browser to `/user/my_vanity_url_value` (replacing `my_vanity_url_value` with the value of that column).

So now, if you go to **http://your.domain.com/profile.php?u=1234**, your browser gets redirected and the URL address bar will say **http://your.domian.com/user/my_name**.

Next, you need to be able to take that unique name and turn it back into the old ugly looking profile page. Two things need to happen here:

1. You need to extend your `profile.php` once more to take an optional vanity name as opposed to a user_id
2. You need to use mod_rewrite to internally route vanity names to `/profile.php`

For the first thing, you simply look for a different `$_GET[]` parameter instead of whatever it is for a user_id. Say it's called `name`: so look at `$_GET['name']`, see if it exists, if it does lookup the user in the user table whose vanity url name is `$_GET['name']`. Return the profile of that user.

For the second thing, you just need to put this in the appropriate place in your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?user/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

---

This is just an example for how to implement something like this. It may be completely inapplicable for what you have, but it should give you an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: Perfect shot.. @JonLin.. you were completely inside the scenario.. With the perfect guesses

Comment: Hey @Jonlin , I have a little confusion..  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     <!--
     window.location="http://www.mydomain/username/";
     // -->
 </script> this kind of redirection, I don't think would be good idea here..so what's advisable

Comment: @HariOm you need the redirect to happen via the script that generates the profile's content

Comment: Consider me not a good coder.. , you said, "you need the redirect to happen via the script that generates the profile's content", please focus on the redirect part because I know the profile content generation, so how do we do redirect "obviously I think may be through the htaccess file, but don't know how, can you please specify.. " .. how.. because I think rest I can do..

Comment: I replaced the old bad looking url with the curtom url by redirecting the page to that url after doing the mysql query but then how do I populate the data on that redirected page..?? please guide me..

Comment: @HariOm It's explained in the answer, starting from ***Next, when you display this profile, say it is via `/profile.php`, your code needs to check a few things.***. Your code checks the `REQUEST_URI` to see how it's being called. If it's called using the ugly way, redirect the browser to the nice looking URL

Comment: am sorry for putting this again.. but when i redirect the user to a nice looking url, that new url will be blank, the problem is populating the new nice looking url page with its content, profile.php could do that but new nice looking url is created on the fly hence its blank because I am not able to populate content to it.. Please do not assume that i am using any framework, my code is plain with pages of codes..