# htaccess codes behaves differently when written in single line and when written in two different lines

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I was trying to learn the htaccess basics but initial step made me go crazy and lost some precious time..

htaccess codes behaves differently when written in single line and when written in two different lines

the code below

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule .* good.html
```

And the code below

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteRule .* good.html
```

Behave differently..

Please explain how it goes..
I guess, its because htaccess checks all the conditions first and then works.. 
but that too should not make it work like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache directives expect to be on a line by itself. So when you have:

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteRule .* good.html
```

The first "word" is the directive, e.g. `RewriteEngine`. It looks for whether it should be on or off, and the next "word" is `on`. So far so good, the rewrite engine is turned on. But there's a bunch of other crap after that and it'll be ignored.

But when you have:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule .* good.html
```

The rewrite engine is turned on like normal. Then a `RewriteRule` directive is processed. The first "word" in the line is `RewriteRule`, so the params are `RewriteRule` *regex* **target** *[flags]*.

So when they're on different lines, everything gets internally rewritten to `good.html`. On the same time, everything after `on` is ignored.

Comment: wow.. that was really was an insight.. may be this was also written in some htaccess jargon and I missed it.. Can you please try to answer this question too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711371
, Thanks in advance..